# Data Matrix Code separators Zebra Printer

Tags: zpl, datamatrix

I have a label with a Data Matrix Code, but i want to some how add a separator between the values. Now it's scanning something like this `163871228928.10.1911:21`, when it should be something like `163/8712289/28.10.19/11:21`

I tried to use `^FD` command between, after and before "##", but no success

`^BXN,10,200^FO150,53^FV#01/HarnessIdShort;02/02;03/HarnessIdShort (z.B. 999):;04/-;05/param_HarnessIdCnt2##01/CustomerPartNo;02/02;03/Customer Part.No.(z.B.: 83767449):;04/VariantFile;05/param3;07/11# #01/Datum;02/04;09/DD.MM.YY# #01/Uhrzeit;02/05;09/HH:MM#^FS`

Comment: How do you receive your scan data? Some terminal program or self written software? If self written, please show your code.

Comment: The parameters are coming from a notepad file and others parameters from an aplication. I think there might be a Zebra command to add some hardcoded separators like "/", for example

Comment: When I use that code you provided with labelary.com between a start and end label command, I see it exactly how you show here. With slashes and everything. Using SCANDIT app on my iPhone.

Comment: I think have you misunderstood my question. How do you read the printed data matrix code back for verification?

Comment: Those are some parameters coming from an application and a notepad file, so you can't see exactly how it appear on the QR code.
@DelphiCoder i check the data matrix code with my QR phone app

Comment: @EdHayes3 
HarnessId id is a current number and it look like "01"
Customer Part Number it look like "8712289
Data and time should look like "28.10.2019" and "10:00"
Those values are comming from an app and a notepad file

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your print process. Obviously the data from this application und the notepad (text?) file is processed somehow before printing, so there must be some point where the slashes are striped off from the data.

Comment: We have an appp, verify a harness, if it's ok, the label is printed. From this app, are coming following parameters HarnessId, Time and Date. In a notepad are some modules numbers added manually there and the apps knows to go to that file and fill the field with correct parameter. Hope you understand :D

Comment: Can you show us the code of the print function of this app? And maybe the content of one of these mysterious notepad files? Without much more details in the question nobody here will be able to help you. Because afik, there are no separators defined in ZPL for Datamatrix content.

Comment: [LabelParameters]
File=autoNEWKZKSK_P1.eti
param1=abcd
param2=BM5RS01102
param3=9890875-01
param4=aaE4P358
param5=8714513
param6=EYE457a

This is in a notepad file. Some parameters which can be modified when needed, like manufacture, module, plant and others.

Comment: You completely lost me. Maybe you can give an example of what the COMPLETE ZPL looks like at each stage of the process, and what you expect the scanned data to look like.

Comment: Please add new details directly to the question. And you still have not shown any code! Without, nobody can help you, because the notepad file data is not enough to explain why you receive a non expected code content!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf), neither the pages for `^BX`, `^FD` or `^FV` specify value separators.

This is something up to you and has to be handled by an algorithm of your scan software, if you wish to extract the different values from the datamatrix content for further processing.